# Light pass the wall

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: Light is behind the wall]

Hello there,

My question is how the light pass the wall and illuminate the elements behind it?I wanted to make an isometric scene with sunlight through inside from window.How can i success this?Light must only come from the window.Like sunset through inside.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there is no gap between the floor and the walls? It would be easier to determine what's happening if you upload your file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I thought about it too first but no.There is no gap between the walls because i made the walls from a cube and then add them to solidify modifier to make them thicker.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation may be that your materials are not able to lower the energy of the light rays.

This may be caused by the use of an **Add shader** (which leads to non-energy conservative behaviour) or even a **high RGB value** as in the following example (shader of all objects is just a diffuse shader with roughness = 0)

**RGB = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)**
[image]

Light cames in the scene from the window and is scattered around. When it goes between two surfaces, it starts bouncing. If it's doesn't lose energy after each bounce, you'll have lit surfaces where there should be shadows instead. The more the surfaces are close to each other, the more the effect is noticeable.

**RGB = (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)**
[image]

Usually is better to keep the RGB values far away from the extremes to achieve more realistic results.

Comment: All elements in the scene has no materials right now.Is this cause that problem too?I only add the window glossy and refraction shader with fresnel in the node editor.I think this isn't relate about this situation.Is this the possible way to make a volumetric light?

Comment: No, when an object has no material is shaded like if it was made by a diffuse shader with RGB (0.8, 0.8, 0.8), so you should not experience that. Your specific problem must be something different from what I showed in this answer. "Volumetric light" is about light interacting with "air", in your image seems that the effect affect only object's surfaces, not what's in between.

Answer (score 0):

The first photo is showing the minimum diffuse value can affect any element inside the room whereever it placed.First,I changed the sample settings and light path settings a bit as shown on the screenshot.And keep the diffuse value at 1.And also changed the light source from sun to spot.Then added a glass material to window.

[image]

After all of these,there was still some tiny brightness on the stool.Then I decided to change the diffuse value to 0.First I changed the sample settings to "Final" and "Path Tracing".Then I modify the light path settings and took a screenshot.

[image]

I think the problem solved with trial and error.Thank you all who is in contribute this question with me.